# Ensuring shell script is being executed by BASH (not csh, ksh, sh etc.)

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

How would you exit-gracefully-upon-entry when invoking a .sh script from anything other than bash?

Answer (score 4):

Make the script executable and prepend:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: In a system without bash installed at all (but with sh, csh, ksh, and all the rest) this does not print the intended error message?

Comment: It will complain that bash can't be found. If you want something more general-purpose or specific than that then you'll have to build your own binary that can be distributed.